# AIDE error: Could not run the App directly as root , [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]

Tags: parsing, installation

Im add project from Eclipse, and Error in AIDE:

**Could not run the App directly as root.
pkg: /.............
[INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]**

What need doing for victory ?

Answer (score 0):

Im delete old app from device, and all working good. Application rebuild and started.